# Mathematica 2D Heat Equation Animation

Tags: animation, wolfram-mathematica, heatmap, differential-equations

I'm working on mapping a temperature gradient in two dimensions and having a lot of trouble. My current approach is to define an Interpolating Function and then try to graph it a lot of times, then animate that table of graphs. Here's what I have so far:

```
RT = 388.726919
R = 1
FUNC == NDSolve[{D[T[x, y, t], t] == 
RT*(D[T[x, y, t], x, x] + D[T[x, y, t], y, y]),

   T[x, y, 0] == 0,
   T[0, y, t] == R*t,
   T[9, y, t] == R*t,
   T[x, 0, t] == R*t,
   T[x, 9, t] == R*t},

  T, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, {t, 0, 6}]
```

So the first two variables just control the rate of change. The equation I'm solving is the basic 2D heat equation, where dT/dt=a(d^2T/dx^2+d^2T/dy^2). The initial conditions set everything to 0, then define the edges as the source of the heat change. Right now it sweeps over a 9x9 block from t=0 to t=6.

The second part attempts to animate the function working.

```
ListAnimate[
Table[
   DensityPlot[T[x, y, t] /. FUNC, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, Mesh -> 9]
, {t, 0, 6}]
]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I'm going crazy trying to figure out why. I first thought it had something to do with the Interpolating Function but now I'm not so confident that the animating code works either. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try "FUNC =" instead of "FUNC =="

Comment: Still no go. The table of graphs is just copies of the same graph.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a quick check:

```
RT = 1
R = 1
FUNC = NDSolve[{D[T[x, y, t], t] == 
     RT*(D[T[x, y, t], x, x] + D[T[x, y, t], y, y]), T[x, y, 0] == 0, 
    T[0, y, t] == R*t,
    T[9, y, t] == R*t,
    T[x, 0, t] == R*t,
    T[x, 9, t] == R*t}, T,
   {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, {t, 0, 6}];
a = Table[
  Plot3D[T[x, y, t] /. FUNC, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, Mesh -> 15, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 9}, {0, 9}, {-1, 10}}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.3 (1 - z)]]], {t, 0, 6}]
Export["c:\anim.gif", a]
```

[image]

PS: A lot of mistakes are avoided by using a lowercase letter as the first char for your symbols...

Comment: -1: For using an explicit path in `Export` and thus revealing that you use a Windows machine.   (+1 for the pretty picture)

Comment: @Simon My actual set of paths for loading and saving info are in my std init cells ... I just replaced svGifPath by "c:\whatever" here for clarity :D

Comment: @belisarius Ooh, standard init cell! Sounds like something for the Toolbag question. I've been meaning to set up something, what do you do apart from some machine / os dependent paths?

Comment: @Timo I was just trying to hide the fact that I _really_ run Windows :(

Comment: @belisarius Oh, don't feel bad, I run MMA on Windows, Linux and OS X, and they all work equally well.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. Any idea why lowercase is preferable to uppercase, or is it just one of the many quirks of Wolfram products? I ended up re-writing the whole thing in Python and MatLab. Mathematica makes it much simpler, as long as you know what you're doing (I didn't!)

Comment: @Tob All Mathematica pre-defined symbols start with uppercase, and some, like I and E are only one char ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Mark -- there is nothing wrong with your program. The problem is that nothing interesting happens to your function after `t=0`: Try having a look at

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Plot3D[T[x, y, t] /. FUNC, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, Mesh -> 9], {t, 0, 6}]]
```

As you can see, all that happens is a scaling, so that when `DensityPlot` rescales each frame independently, they end up looking identical :)

Comment: This is what I thought. I was fooling around with ColorFunctionScaling->False but I couldn't get it to work as a function, so I ended up having solid colors for each frame.