# 2D Heat Equation Mathematica not solving analitically (DSolve) or numerically (NDSolve), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, pde

my goal is to solve the following 2d heat conduction equation, along with initial and boundary conditions:

```
pde = D[u[x, y, t], t] == (c^2)*(D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);

ic = {u[x,y,0] == 0};
bc = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, y, t] == k, u[x, 0, t] == 0, u[x, b, t] == 0, 
u[a, y, t] == 0};
```

...but something always goes wrong when i input

```
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}]
```

I tried changing the conditions a bit to see if that is a problem on mathematica, and sometimes it works ([example of this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342585/mathematica-2d-heat-equation-animation)). I suspect there is something wrong with the derivative, but I tried using D[u[x,y,t],x]./x->0 == k but still it doesnt work. Is it even possible to solve this in Mathematica?

Comment: Oh! Just to be clear, this is a 2d heat conduction equation of a bar of size [a x b] that is continuously heated from the left at a rate k, that is initially at temperature 0, and the top, bottom and right sides are kept at temperature 0 as well.

Comment: You might look at each of these and see if you find something that helps you. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=dsolve+heat+equation

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that before I posted, theres nothing there...

Comment: I'd suggest NDSolve, e.g. `NDSolveValue[{de, bc, ic}, u, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, {t, 0, 10}]`. Of course `a` and `b` must have numerical values.